# How do I use a term as contextual filter correctly?

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I'm using Drupal 8.

I have a book content type that uses a vocabulary called "book type" as an entity reference field.

I have basic page content type which also uses the the vocabulary "book type" as an entity reference field.

So both of the content types are using the same vocabulary.

What I'm trying to do is filter the books by the chosen book type on the basic page content type, but I just can't figure it out. Here's what I tried.

[image: drupal view]

[image: drupal view]
[image: drupal view]
[image: drupal view]
[image: drupal view]

**This is the book content type, which uses the vocabulary "book type" in an entity reference field**
[image: drupal view]
[image: drupal view]

**This is the basic page content type which also use the vocabulary "book type" in an entity reference field**
[image: drupal view]
[image: drupal view]
[image: drupal view]

This is my second try with the help of prkos:
[image: drupal view]

Comment: That type is the field that is used on both CTs? It's not an Entity Reference field? Maybe a text list? BTW narrow your screen next time when taking screenshots so you don't have so much empty spaces making them harder to read.

Comment: @prkos Thanks for checking it out! Yes the field is in used on both CTs and It's an entity reference field. Sorry about the images, I just uploaded better ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Relationships for matching through ER fields, IDs are enough so it's enough to use the ER field Contextual matching directly.

Instead of the ID Contextual filter add the Contextual filter for the ER field and configure it:
`When the filter value is NOT available`
**Provide default value**
**Taxonomy term ID from URL**
**Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks**
**Limit terms by vocabulary**
**[Your vocabulary]**
**Filter to items that share any term**
`When the filter value IS available or a default is provided`
**Specify validation criteria**
**Taxonomy term ID**
**[Your vocabulary]**

Set other options according to your needs.

You can test it by entering a Taxonomy ID into the Views Preview field, you should get only the nodes that reference that term.

When you place the Block in a theme region also configure the Contextual option, it won't work without it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! When i type in a Taxonomy ID I just get "related book block" as the result, which is the name of the block.

Comment: Did you configure the No results text? Maybe you're entering an ID that isn't referenced from any content? What happens when you enter `all` into Preview? Add to the question info with the configuration for the Contextual.

Comment: I just configured the no results text, so now when I enter a known taxonomy id i just get "no results found", and i'm 100% sure the taxonomy term is correct. The taxonomy term id of "resources" is 11, so i just typed in 11 on views preview field.

Comment: Is your last screnshot correct? It says your Contextual is Content ID, and not the ER field.

Comment: Yes the i uploaded the correct screenshot, but wow it seems like i didn't follow your instructions correctly. I cannot fiend an Entity reference field on the list of contextual filters. Is it called something else? Is the one called "Has taxonomy term ID"?

Comment: It seems to be called Related book in your screenshots, it will be listed in the Content Category. But be careful to add the field that is part of the CT that you're listing in Views (Book). Did you use the same field on both CTs (same machine name)? It's easier to match in Views if you had.

Comment: That works. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad to help :)